# CSS codes doesn't work correctly after moving in head to style.css

Tags: html, css

I have created CSS styles in  head tags like

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
  .... Here
</style>
</head>
```

After I moved my all CSS codes from the *style.css*

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mobile.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/animations.css" />
</head>
```

... then some CSS codes don't worked.

for example  some `@media all and() {....}`

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you see your files referenced properly in the browser's development console?

Comment: @AnthonyE yes i see all codes in developer console.

Comment: @AnthonyE some css codes not working correctly on mobile also but that css codes working computer browsers.

Comment: And when you say they don't work, do you mean none of them are working? Do you have a completely unstyled page? Any errors in the browser dev console?

Comment: i think you shall post which codes arent working (or at least one as an example);

Comment: @AnthonyE for example [TEST PAGE](http://www.ecowebtr.com/test/test.html) You can see the test page. Resize the browser and you can see the 'a' that is a button. Please click it and left sidebar will open and if you change the browser height the scroll working on there. But if you open test page with your mobile the scroll doesn't work.

Comment: @AnthonyE this is working example. The css codes are in `<head><styletype="text/css"> .... Here</style></head>` [WORKING](http://www.ecowebtr.com/test/test2.html)

Comment: @freestock.tk This is the problem example [PROBLEM](http://www.ecowebtr.com/test/test.html) and this is working example [WORKING](http://www.ecowebtr.com/test/test2.html) . There are same css codes. I just moved my css codes from the style.css file.

Comment: Please supply a runnable demo in you question to make it easier for people to help.

Comment: @VincentOrback i have added demo pages please check my comments.

Comment: Yes, it’s just that those links will probably die some day and then no one will be helped with the answers given. Also your answers should contain the demo code.

Comment: @DevStud I understand the situation but here on Stackoverflow the questions must be minimal (yet complete) so you shall isolate the issue on an element, instead of pick the entire page; It would let it easier to people understand and then help you;

Comment: Your “not working” example embeds only one single stylesheet, `css/style.css` – so where are the other two that you mentioned in your question …?

Comment: @CBroe First this is working [DEMO](http://www.ecowebtr.com/test/test2.html) and this is not working [DEMO](http://www.ecowebtr.com/test/test.html)

Comment: @CBroe Please note check the second demo in your mobile to see what is the problem correctly.

Comment: `http://www.ecowebtr.com/test/test2.html` embeds no external stylesheets at all, and `http://www.ecowebtr.com/test/test.html` only embeds one single external stylesheet, `css/style.css`. So, again – where are those other two stylesheets you mentioned in your question …?

Comment: An advice: rebuild the question only with the "click" button (which only appears on the working demo) to illustrate the problem. otherwise it will be too hard to people understand what is going on (the page have several elements);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd have to see all rules and stylesheets in both states (before and after moving them to separate files). But the CSS rules also depend on their order of appearance: Most likely now you have them in a different order. What comes last overwrites what comes before, unless the latter one does not apply because it's in a media query. But if for example originally you had this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .my_div { width: 400px; }
}
```

and somewhere later

```
.my_div { width: 750px; }
```

, then `.my_div` will have a width of 750px, also on smaller screens - the second rule is valid for all screen sizes and therefore overwrites the first rule.

So if you had something like this and put those two rules into different external stylesheets, with the media queries coming *after* the general rules, their order is different, so now the media query will be effective, since it's not overwritten anymore by another rule for the same element.

(This is a very simple example, but the principle is the same for everything, also for example for `display: block` vs. display: `inline-block` for the `li` items in a nav list)

Comment: Dear Thank you for your answer. Just i need to learn. Why the scroll element doesn't work on mobile. Please look at this [DEMO](http://www.ecowebtr.com/test/test.html). Please check it on your computer and mobile device. 

Resize the page height on your computer and see the left sidebar will scrolling. But the scroll doesn't work on mobile.

Comment: thank you Dear. You give me the idea and i fixed the problem. But i don't understand why someone gives me - vote  :(

Comment: probably you should have included at least *some* of your CSS code, since otherwise it's hard to find the real reason for sure.

Comment: yes Dear thank you. So can you explain me what is the different `@media all and () {...}` and `@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {...}` I think that is same think ?

Comment: `all` is really everything - it also includes printing, screen readers etc., `screen` is only valid for screen, and for example not for print.